# Have objective c code remember places user has touched on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tweak

I am working on making a Swype keyboard for iOS and I was wondering in which way would I get the objective c code to remember the keys the user has hovered over.

```c
%hook UIKBKeyplaneView

- (void)setState:(int)arg1 forKey:(id)arg2 {
    if (![ISController sharedInstance].isSwyping) {
        %orig;
    } else {
        %orig(2,arg2);
    }
}

%end

%hook UIKeyboardImpl

- (void)longPressAction {
    if (![ISController sharedInstance].isSwyping) {
        %orig;
    }
}

%end

%hook UIKeyboardLayoutStar
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    %orig;
    [[ISController sharedInstance] forwardMethod:self sel:_cmd touches:touches event:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    %orig;
    [[ISController sharedInstance] forwardMethod:self sel:_cmd touches:touches event:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    %orig;
    [[ISController sharedInstance] forwardMethod:self sel:_cmd touches:touches event:event];
}

%end

%hook UIKeyboard
-(void)removeFromSuperview{
    [[ISController sharedInstance].suggestionsView hideAnimated:YES];
    %orig;
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    %orig;
    [ISController sharedInstance].suggestionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, frame.origin.y-30, frame.size.width, 30);
}
%end
```

As of right now, I have the keyboard showing the users path but it doesn't remember where the user has had their finger over. Ex: If the user were to Swype the word "the" it wouldn't display the "th" it would only display the ending character "e".

Comment: Just for your information iOS 13 will feature a swipe keyboard. See WWDC 2019 videos. https://www.engadget.com/2019/06/03/apple-ios-13-quickpath-swipe-keyboard/

Comment: @HerbertBay I know I'm working on one for iOS 12 and below